# the mesh of the pig mask is when i select to parenting armature to mesh with automatic weights

Tags: modeling, mesh

the mesh of the pig mask is when i select to  parenting armature to mesh with automatic weights, this is the image of when it deforms. I am doing something wrong ?

[image]

Comment: You mean you have a "pig mask" mesh that you are trying to parent to an armature, but when you do, it deforms like in the image?

Comment: Hello !! Thank you very much for answering :D But I already solve, the problem was the two bones that come out of the head were the problem, and I had to disable the warp box of those two bones. An apology about my english.